# C getchar input problems

Tags: c, getchar

I need to receive a single line of characters and convert them from the base they are written in to a decimal base, *as soon as a character is typed*.

I did this by using the following function:

```
int inToDec(int base) //My assumption is that Enter will not be pressed as the first character - if it is, I am not sure what to do in that case
{
    int numdec=0, c;//decimalized number, a variable for character inpu
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        if(c >= 97)//Checks if the char is an actual char
            c = c - 'a' - 1;
        else//or a digit char
            c = c;
        numdec += numdec * base + c;//every time another char is inputted, it multiplies the numdec by the base and adds the char's value in decimal base - which is essentially the algorithm for conversion to decimal base.
    }
    return numdec;
}
```

My main():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funcs.h"

int main()
{
    int option, fbase, tbase, num1, num2;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option)
        {
        case 1:
            scanf("%d",&fbase);
            num1 = inToDec(fbase);
            num2 = inToDec(fbase);
            outFromDec(num1+num2,fbase);
            break;
        case 2:
            scanf("%d",&fbase);
            num1 = inToDec(fbase);
            num2 = inToDec(fbase);
            if(num1>=num2)
                outFromDec(num1-num2,fbase);
            else
                outFromDec(num2-num1,fbase);
            break;
        case 3:
            scanf("%d",&fbase);
            scanf("%d",&tbase);
            num1 = inToDec(fbase);
            outFromDec(num1,tbase);
            break;
        }
    }while(option != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Except that when I input the number(after the option and the desired base) and type Enter to continue to the next one, suddenly it starts to print a character time after time without end. What did I do wrong and how do I fix it? Or, if you do not want to explain some obvious fact to a noob, where do I read about it (preferably without too much heavy duty tech-talk, as I am relatively new to programming).

outFromDec() -

```
void outFromDec(int num, int base) //converts num into the base given and prints
{
    int count = 0 , temp = num, i;
    char c;
    while(temp != 0)
    {
        temp /= base;
        count++;
    }
    temp = num;
    do
    {
        for(i=1;i<count;i++)
            temp /= base;
        if(temp<=9)
            c = '0' + temp;
        else
            c = 'a' + temp - 1;
        putchar(c);
        count--;
        temp = num / temp;
    }while(temp != 0);
}
```

Comment: You are not printing any thing and on which platform you are?

Comment: Platform? Don't get what you are asking, but if you mean OS and software, then I am using Visual C++ 2010 on Windows 7.

Comment: I was asking about OS. Now post your `outFromDec` function, it will help us to debug your code. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code has problems:

```
while(c = getchar() != '\n' && c != EOF)
```

Not enough parentheses — assignment is a low priority operator.  It should be:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
```

Another set of problems is in the conversion code in the body of the loop:

```
    if (c >= 97)
        c = c - 'a' - 1;
    else
        c = c;
    numdec += numdec * base + c;
```

The choice of `97` is presumably the ASCII or ISO 8859-*n* or Unicode code point for `a`. This ignores upper case letters, punctuation, and treats the digits `0` to `9` as though they 48..57.  You probably need to use `#include <ctype.h>`. It also does not validate that the 'digit' is valid for the base.

However, on the first call to `intToDec()`, the first character read is a newline, left over by `scanf()`, so the first number is always zero, if you enter the numbers one per line as you're told to.

When you finally get to `outToDec()`, you have some interesting numerology. I added `printf()` statements to track function entry and exit, and also for key points in the loop:

```
void outFromDec(int num, int base)
{
    printf("-->> %s: %d %d\n", __func__, num, base);
    int count = 0, temp = num, i;
    char c;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        temp /= base;
        count++;
    }
    printf("Count: %d\n", count);
    temp = num;
    do
    {
        printf("count: %d; temp = %d\n", count, temp);
        for (i = 1; i < count; i++)
            temp /= base;
        if (temp <= 9)
            c = '0' + temp;
        else
            c = 'a' + temp - 1;
        putchar(c);
        count--;
        temp = num / temp;
    } while (temp != 0);
    printf("<<-- %s\n", __func__);
}
```

The `__func__` is a predefined identifier in C99 containing the function name. It may not be available to you in MSVC; if not, replace it with the function name.

For the inputs `1`, `9`, `9`, the output from the program was:

```
-->> inToDec: 9
<<-- inToDec: 0
-->> inToDec: 9
<<-- inToDec: 57
-->> outFromDec: 57 9
Count: 2
count: 2; temp = 57
6count: 1; temp = 9
9count: 0; temp = 6
6count: -1; temp = 9
9count: -2; temp = 6
```

And the count continued to decrease and the 6's and 9's continued to alternate.  You seem to be trying to isolate the digits with the most significant digit (MSD) discovered first.  The loop determining `count` is correct; the loop printing the digits clearly isn't. You should be able to take it from there; it is routine debugging. Note how I used the print statements to see what was going on. If you can't resolve it by just looking at the code, print out the result of every expression, if necessary.

I observe that to print 57 in base 10, you'd discover that there are 2 digits to print (`count == 2`). The first digit would be found by dividing by the base (10) `count-1` times; this would give you 5 to print. You probably need to subtract 5 * 10 from the number so that the next (in this case, the last) time around the loop, you'd start with just 7, which you'd print.  The loop would stop.  You should ensure the loop breaks if `count` ever goes negative.

This is an expensive way of formatting a 10-digit 32-bit number (or even more so a 19-digit 64-bit number).  It can be made to work, though.  The standard procedure collects the digits in reverse order and arranges to print them out in the inverse order.  (`number % base` gives you the digit to be printed; `number /= base` reduces the number of digits left to process.)

---

As happens quite often, the OP is under artificial constraints and may not use strings.  Yuck!

Here is a 'read an integer' function that is plausibly robust. It does assume 2's complement arithmetic; it contains an assertion that should fire if it was ever run on a machine that was sign-magnitude or 1's complement (but I haven't tested it; I don't have any such machines available to test on).

Note that the code accumulates the number as a negative number, and makes it positive at the end if it should be positive. This makes it easier to deal with INT_MIN than trying to accumulate it as a positive `int`.

For the purposes of the exercise, I'm treating the system as though `sizeof(intmax_t) == sizeof(int)` (and hence `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)` and `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long long)` too); this technique would work if the integer type were `intmax_t` instead of `int`.  Note that the C standard does not rule out this supposed configuration (but the standard requires that `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) >= 64` to be a conforming implementation).

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Read an integer from stdin without prompt: code is not allowed to use strings! */
enum { E_OK = 0, E_EOF = -1, E_INVCHAR = -2, E_OVERFLOW = -3 };

extern int read_an_int(int *value);

int read_an_int(int *value)
{
    int number = 0;
    int c;
    int pos_neg = +1;

    assert(-INT_MAX != INT_MIN);    // Probably 2's complement

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && isspace(c))
        ;
    if (c == '-')
    {
        pos_neg = -1;
        c = getchar();
    }
    else if (c == '+')
    {
        pos_neg = +1;
        c = getchar();
    }
    if (c == EOF)
        return E_EOF;
    if (!isdigit(c))
        return E_INVCHAR;

    number = '0' - c;   /* Negated digit */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && isdigit(c))
    {
        int d = '0' - c; /* Negated digit */
        if (number < INT_MIN / 10 || (number == INT_MIN/10 && d < INT_MIN % 10))
            return E_OVERFLOW;
        //printf("N1 %d; d %d; ", number, d);
        number = number * 10 + d;
        //printf("N2 %d\n", number);
    }
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetc(c, stdin);

    if (pos_neg != -1)
    {
        //printf("Should be switched (%d)(%d)\n", pos_neg, number);
        if (number == INT_MIN)
            return E_OVERFLOW;
        number = -number;
        //printf("Should be positive (%d)(%d)\n", pos_neg, number);
    }

    *value = number;
    return E_OK;
}

static void gobble_input(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (isdigit(c) || c == '+' || c == '-')
        {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            break;
        }
        printf("Skip %c\n", c);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int rc;
    int number;

    while ((rc = read_an_int(&number)) != E_EOF)
    {
        switch (rc)
        {
        case E_INVCHAR:
            printf("Invalid character spotted\n");
            gobble_input();
            break;
        case E_OVERFLOW:
            printf("Input would have overflowed integer range %d..%d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
            break;
        case E_OK:
            printf("Input number: %d\n", number);
            break;
        default:
            assert(0);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The test data file I used was:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11
+123
1234
56789
+123456789
2147483647
2147483648
+000000123456789
000000123456789
-0000
+0000
-1
-2
-9
-21
-321
-4321
-2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483649
# Bogus data or partially bogus data
-
+
-213a
+213a
+.213
3.14159E+23
```

The output from that was:

```
Input number: 0
Input number: 1
Input number: 2
Input number: 3
Input number: 4
Input number: 5
Input number: 6
Input number: 7
Input number: 8
Input number: 9
Input number: 11
Input number: 123
Input number: 1234
Input number: 56789
Input number: 123456789
Input number: 2147483647
Input would have overflowed integer range -2147483648..2147483647
Input number: 123456789
Input number: 123456789
Input number: 0
Input number: 0
Input number: -1
Input number: -2
Input number: -9
Input number: -21
Input number: -321
Input number: -4321
Input number: -2147483647
Input number: -2147483648
Input would have overflowed integer range -2147483648..2147483647
Invalid character spotted
Skip  
Skip B
Skip o
Skip g
Skip u
Skip s
Skip  
Skip d
Skip a
Skip t
Skip a
Skip  
Skip o
Skip r
Skip  
Skip p
Skip a
Skip r
Skip t
Skip i
Skip a
Skip l
Skip l
Skip y
Skip  
Skip b
Skip o
Skip g
Skip u
Skip s
Skip  
Skip d
Skip a
Skip t
Skip a
Skip 

Invalid character spotted
Invalid character spotted
Input number: -213
Invalid character spotted
Skip 

Input number: 213
Invalid character spotted
Skip 

Invalid character spotted
Input number: 213
Input number: 3
Invalid character spotted
Input number: 14159
Invalid character spotted
Input number: 23
```

Note that the last line provided 3 valid numbers (and two invalid characters, the `.` and the `E`).

It isn't particularly easy; that's why these things are coded in library functions.  Also, the 'no strings' requirement means I can't do decent error reporting when there are invalid characters or overflows.

Comment: After I posted this I changed that due to other posts I saw do that. But yes, as haccks said, it is not the cause sadly.

Comment: The code didn't even compile successfully for me until I fixed that (I compile with very stringent warning options, and `-Werror` so any warning is treated as an error).  I've now reproduced the problem typing `1`, `5` and `6` on separate lines (getting a screen full of `5j` pairs). I'll debug further. If your compile was not complaining about this mistake, you should ratchet up the compiler warnings so it does; if it still can't, get a better compiler.

Comment: A complete debugging procedure. Nice.

Comment: I wish I knew routine debugging procedures... Anywhere to read about them? How do I handle the input problem? Since this needs to run on Unix as well, I can't really use fflush(stdin).

Comment: Look at answers, especially my answers, on SO? I routinely give advice and add debug code, etc. (For instance, from [today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164204/s/20165129#20165129) — the 'function to dump a data structure' meme is common in my debugging recommendations.) For input issues, first define what input is expected. If the program is interactive, give prompts — write a function to prompt and read, in fact. I frequently use `fgets()` to read a complete line of input and then parse that, often with `sscanf()`, avoiding most problems with newlines.

Comment: Echo what you read, too. The most basic validation is to print what you just read. When I saw the zero from `inToDec()`, I knew immediately that there was a problem; it didn't take me many seconds to recognize what the problem was, but I've debugged that sort of code before. (So, part of the art of debugging is to have done a lot of it. Fortunately, just writing lots of code gives you lots of practice at debugging!) But plunging ahead assuming the program read A when in fact it read B is a recipe for stressful debugging and hair-tearing. And always check the return status from input functions!

Comment: The thing is, I am under strict guidelines not to use strings and arrays, which means that I HAVE to receive characters one after another.

Comment: That's a pain...also, such artificial restrictions on good solutions have to be documented in the question, because no-one in their right mind is going to devise a solution with their hands tied behind their back unless you tell us that your teacher is tying your hands behind your back.  I guess that faced with the problem, I'd write a function to skip over white space, read digits, and stop reading on a non-digit. If I get a non-digit, non-white space (a letter, for example, or an unexpected punctuation character) before getting digits, the function would report an error.

Comment: Solved the input issues with a `getchar()` before the input loop to swallow that leftover newline(used a static variable in the function to make sure it happens only once), now debugging that second loop in `outFromDec()`.

Comment: Didn't get half of what was written in the second part... and don't have the time to read about it due to other homework... life is such an unfair thing. Thanks anyway, I'm pretty close to zeroing in on what is wrong with my loop(solved the infinite printing issue, now need to work on my algorithm's accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Windows, add a `fflush (stdin)` just before the loop in which the `getchar()` is. That is:

```
int inToDec(int base) //My assumption is that Enter will not be pressed as the first character - if it is, I am not sure what to do in that case
{
    int numdec=0, c;//decimalized number, a variable for character inpu
    fflush (stdin);  /* flushes input buffer */
    while(c = getchar() != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        if(c >= 97)//Checks if the char is an actual char
            c = c - 'a' - 1;
        else//or a digit char
            c = c;
        numdec += numdec * base + c;//every time another char is inputted, it multiplies the numdec by the base and adds the char's value in decimal base - which is essentially the algorithm for conversion to decimal base.
    }
    return numdec;
}
```

Comment: `fflush (stdin)` will cause **undefined behavior** if not on MS-DOS.